# Why is the tableview being scrolled after adding into a uialertview and seting pagingEnabled as NO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview

I add a `UITableview` into a `UIAlertview`, and set the `pagingEnabled` as `NO`, but when I dragged the table, it is still scrolling/paging left or right! Why? I found that in iPhone 3GS, it can not to be scrolled/paged, but in iPhone 4, it can be scrolled/paged. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, although UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView and thus has pagingEnabled property, UITableViews don't actually support paging, thus setting that property has little effect.

UITableViews normally shouldn't scroll horizontally. If it does, then most likely the UITableView frame is out of its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that the UIAlertVidw's frame in ios has limit